# Create new list by comparing first row item in first list to items in second list

Tags: python, list, compare

I'm new to python and coming from Matlab and am still adjusting to using lists as opposed to arrays. I've got two lists, and I'm trying to create a third with items from the first if the items in each row match any element from the second. Essentially, I've got

```
list1 = [['name1',height1,length1],['name2',height2,length2]...['name9',height9,length9]
list2 = ['name1','name9']
list3 = []
```

and want something like

```
for row in list1
    if first element (namex) in row is in list2
        append row to list 3
```

I want a list3 that will contain the rows of list1 that have a first item that matches an item in list2.

```
list3 = [['name1',height1,lenght1],['name9',height9,length9]]
```

I've tried two different ways of doing this, but both result in a blank list3:

```
list3 = [item for item in list1 if item[0] in list2]
```

and

```
for rows in list1:
    if list1[0] in list2:
        list3.append(rows)
```

Knowing that lists cannot be indexed in the same way as arrays, how can I get similar functionality here?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: So what's wrong with the code you posted? The list comprehension produces your expected output, doesn't it?

Comment: @Rawing list three appears empty after executing the code

Comment: Umm, no, no it doesn't. Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: @Rawing hmmm, there must be an issue earlier in my code in creating the lists? I will look and see. Thank you for confirming the method!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first proposed method worked just fine for me.

For the second method to work, it needs to be redacted as follows:

```
list3 = []
for row in list1:
    if row[0] in list2:
        list3.append(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `if` check should use `rows[0]` not `list1[0]`.

```
for row in list1:
    if row[0] in list2:
        list3.append(rows)
```

This can be condensed into a list comprehension.

```
list3 = [row for row in list1 if row[0] in list2]
```